# Check if one unix_timestamp is greater than another

Tags: mysql, if-statement, field

I've built this SQL Query that should place the highest date value inside `field_result` but it isn't working as intended.

```
SELECT
    field_one,
    field_two,
    IF(((field_one IS NOT NULL AND field_one <> '') AND
        (field_one > TableB.field_two)),
       unix_timestamp(field_one),
       unix_timestamp(TableB.field_two)) AS result
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableB.id = TableA.id
```

The condition is very simple.

- `field_one` must exist, and contain some sort of value.
- If `field_one > field_two` show `field_one` otherwise show `field_two`

It produces the result

```
"field_one", "field_two", "field_result"
"1495681346","1500328106","1500328106"
"1500342725","1500328106","1500328106"
"1499922505","1500329807","1500329807"
"1500343148","1500328106","1500328106"
"1500329593","1500328106","1500328106"
```

For some reason on `row 2` the value for `field_result` is not `1500342725` (this value is approx `14619` greater than `1500328106`).

I think I've got the correct syntax, but I'm unsure because the result isn't what I'm expecting

Comment: Please cleanup your query and give us a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the greater of two fields then consider using MySQL's `GREATEST()` function.

```
SELECT
    field_one,
    field_two,
    GREATEST(COALESCE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field_one), -1),
             COALESCE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field_two), -1)) AS result
FROM TableA
```

Comment: This is not the query I gave you.  What are the types of the two field columns?  Are they a date type?

Comment: Give me a reproducible example.

Comment: I created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/388c0/1), and your example is actually correct, I was running `unx_timestamp` on an already formatted timestamp `field` (thus causing the incorrect result). Thank you very much.